# Multicast over 802.11b wireless

Tags: wifi, multicast

How do wireless routers behave with regards to multicast traffic? Given that nature of the shared physical medium routing to specific ports is not possible. Therefore, are mutlticast packets essentially broadcast or are they redundantly transmitted multiple times per multicast group participant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains

http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3433451/Implementing-Wi-Fi-Multicast-Solutions.htm

Don't forget that thick and thin coaxial Ethernet was a broadcast medium too. Early 10-base-T hubs also transmitted all packets to all ports. So I imagine the multicast inventors gave some thought to multicast delivery on a LAN with a broadcast medium.

Comment: Very good article. The explanation of DTIM interval will certainly be helpful to me as well. Thanks.